# assembly store values in given location

Tags: assembly, embedded

Give an assembly language assembler directive statement(s) that initialize the values `15`, `-25`, `F7H`, string `\CpE363`" at memory locations `200H`, `201H`, `202`, and `300H` respectively (note for the string, the address specified is a starting address).

---

I am trying to solve it but am not sure

```
ORG 200H
START:
MOV A,#15 
MOV A,#0E7H  
MOV A,#0F7H  

ORG 300H
Temp: DB “CpE363”
STOP:AJMP $
END
```

Comment: Looks like homework.  Have you tried anything or put any effort into solving this on your own?

Comment: what instruction set?

Comment: sounds like you are supposed to just use directives and not any instructions.  if you want those values at those addresses.  putting instructions there is not the same as initializing those locations.  If the program is supposed to put those things there then that is another story you need code that doesnt run in the space you want to fill...

Answer (score 2):

The instructions on common CPUs are encoded as byte(s) themselves, so doing:

```
    ORG 200H
    MOV A,#15
```

will produce highly likely two or three bytes (depending on the CPU your assembler is targeting), for example for 8051 CPU `mov A,#immediate` is encoded as two bytes `74h, 0Fh`, and due to `ORG` directive the byte `74h` is at address 200h and byte `0Fh` at address 201h, so you failed your task.

The task already contains hint, talking about *"assembler directive"*, not about instructions, so your `DB` defining string seems like the thing you should use also for the three numeric values.

(you can still define those three bytes also as instructions, if you would check which instruction(s) does assemble as those three requested bytes, but then you are not using "assembler directive", but "CPU instruction")

And about the string definition... if you want C-like string, then it needs also zero terminator: `DB “CpE363”,0` would work like that, adding one more zero byte after it. Raw strings without terminator are usable only by code which knows the length of string, while the "terminated" strings can be searched by code for terminator value, so you can pass only pointers of them to subroutines (but figuring out length then costs extra runtime, doing the checking of bytes for terminator value).

And putting `STOP:AJMP $` after it is probably useless, because such source code only defining bytes as requested, doesn't contain any intentional instruction to be executed (you can still execute the data defined and the CPU will decode them as some instructions and do who-knows-what). Also if one would treat your code as is, and execute at "START:" the CPU would execute the three `MOV` instructions as expected, then it would hit some memory content at addresses 206h..2FFh (if it would be filled with zeroes, those are decoded by CPU as instruction `NOP`, so the CPU would just proceed through them step by step) and then later at address 300h it would execute the string as CPU instructions (I don't have disassembler for 8051 at hand, so I can't tell which instructions would be decoded from that string), and it would probably reach that `STOP:` label in quite unexpected state, if it would reach it at all.

That's one feature of "Von Neumann architecture" computers, that data bytes and instructions occupy the same type of memory (and the memory can be used for both), and the CPU has no way to tell which is which, so maintaining (by the programmer) the correct flow of CPU through instruction-only memory content is critical. Once you lose it due to some mistake, the CPU will execute whatever memory content it does reach and act accordingly to those values (in extremely unlikely cases with some sensitive device connected the CPU may accidentally even destroy the peripheral device by executing some I/O command, for example some of the old CRT monitors with old VGA cards could have been forced to display whole image into single point of the screen-shield, effectively burning a dot into the phosphor layer in short time - but I never heard of code doing this unintentionally by mistake/bug, at most people did just erase whole their disks or jammed printers, etc and in 99% executing data by accident ended by machine reset without any more harm).

And that's why there is that `AJMP $` in ordinary code at the end, jumping infinitely at itself, preventing CPU to start wandering into memory beyond the designed code and executing some random nonsense. But in your task there is no code to be executed, so there's no point to add the infinite cycle at end either.